# Flash - punctuation marks get aligned wrongly

Tags: flash, alignment, right-to-left

In my flash application I am using a typewriter effect, to make it seem as if text is written on the fly. When I do so, my punctuation marks (question mark, dot, ect.) get aligned to the wrong direction (to the right).  I am writing in Hebrew (right-to-left). What could be a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so three hours later I am here with a solution. I hope it saves time for other people.

Flash cs5 has got a built in support for rtl languages. You need to enable it:
1. Change your project publish settings to flash player 10 (only supported there)
2. Go to edit --> preferences --> text --> show right-to-left text options
2. Change your textfield's type to tlftext (it's a new option that suddenly shows)
3. Set your alignment

Now, if you just want to set text statically your fine, but if you want to set text using some as3 code you need to do the following as wel:

Create a new text format, give it the following settings and apply it to your text field:

```
var tfFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
tfFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
txt.setTextFormat(tfFormat);
```

And that's it. Good luck to you all.